# Python list of lists convention

Tags: python, list, set, tuples

I have a list something like this bellow (y). Now, what I wanna do is to remove the object `[n,m]`. If `n` matches some value. I therefor ponder on if lists of lists (`m` will change multiple times during runtime, while `n` is static) are the way to go for this? And if there's a cleaner way then my "for" statement to do this. Performance here is top concern.

```
y = [[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'C']]

def f(x):
    for x in y:
       if x[0] == 2:
            y.remove(x)

print(f(2)) # [[1,'A'],[3,'C']]
```

Comment: What is `f(2):`? Did you intend to define a function?

Comment: your implementation is incorrect, just so you know, but I'm not sure what you are asking exactly

Comment: What is `f(2):` supposed to be?  That is invalid syntax.

Comment: I guess you meant `def f(x):`?

Comment: i understand you needed to type "def f():". im just new to python and want to have "correct" code. Seems like dictionary's are the way forward!

Comment: @Frallan No worries.  In general its a good idea to have *working* code that can be tested.  We were able to guess what you meant this time, but if you ask a more complicated question, you are much less likely to get answers.

Comment: @calebgoodman Haha, i keep that in mind! i was gonna write pseudo code but hey... that's basically Python :D

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple pairs of `[n, m]` with the same value of `n`, e.g. `[2, 'B'], [2, 'C']`?  If so, a dictionary is not a suitable data structure.  If so, deletion is simple, e.g. `if 2 in y: del y[2]`.

Comment: voting to close as "primarily opinion based" because OP stated that "performance is top concern"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) instead of a list of lists because you can check if something is in a dictionary fast. Then, you can use `del` to delete that key:

```
y = {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}

def f(x):
   if x in y:
       del y[x]

f(2)
print(y)  # {1: 'A', 3: 'C'}
```

Comment: ooh so clean..! thank you! my keys will be websockets in my implementation but that's not an issue i assume

Comment: @Frallan the websocket objects have to be "hashable" for them to be dictionary keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with list comprehension:

```
>>> x = 2
>>> y = [[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'C']]
>>> [l for l in y if l[0] != x]
[[1, 'A'], [3, 'C']]
```